# How to make hierarchical structed database in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to achieve a **hierarchical structured database in mongodb**. 
Can someone explain me how to structure this

---

Something Like this
[image]

Here all the leaf nodes will have multiple data, like an array. For eg. all leaf nodes will have employee details.

---

Or to understand better, can i **achieve database like this**
[image]

---

Additional info as requested:

Suppose I have an ecommerce website, and I wish to make one node for each type of item. And each node will individually have list of products.

*Eg. Main nodes - Food, Stationery, Games

And Food has list of food item each as a document
Similarly Stationary has many items and games also.*

Comment: Can you put down a number after each hierchy (suppose after an year, how many pavement improvement entries, how many reconstruction entries for 1 pavement improvement and so on). Share the estimate

Comment: One of the main aspects of modeling data is the usage patterns; means, what are your main queries are going to be adn how often? Based on this, the model will take shape. Please post this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1:** In mongodb, you can have embedded document as following

```
{
    parent: { 
        level1: [{
           level2: [{
              myField: myValue1
           }, 
           {
              myField: myValue2
           }]
        },
        {
           level2: [{
              myField: myValue1
           }, 
           {
              myField: myValue2
           }] 
    }
}
```

Note that default limit on each mongodb document is 16mb. So this approach will work fine as long as your children are not too many in number to exceed the document limit. Although you can but I wouldn't suggest to change the default document size limit unless there is no other way.

**Approach 2:** Create different collections for each with a reference field for parent

```
//Collection1: parent
{
   id: "1", 
   ....
}

//Collection1 : level1
{
  id: "dsf",
  parentId: 1,
  ...
}

//Collection1: level2
{
  id: "bs",
  level1Id: "dsf",
  ...
}
```

Comment: In your approach 2 wouldn't it be better if i use key level_Id in all collection so that i can recursively iterate back (incase i land up on a random document) ?

Comment: Yes, good idea. Write down insert query and this should give you more clarity whether to do this or not. If this answer helped you, please upvote and accept the answer